# Python: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable Spider Script issue

Tags: python

I am working on building a link checking script to be used in monitoring a domain I manage.  I am getting an error about the 9th url is ran through the findLinks() function.  I am not sure what is causing it and I could really use a fresh set of eyes.  This is in v2.7 and can be run with the following command:

$ python link-checker.py -d http://google.com

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse
import time

# start execution timer
start_time = time.time()

# Control which channel 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='broken link checker')
parser.add_argument('-d', help='a domain name with scheme', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# configfuration
startUrl = args['d']
linksToCrawl = []
visitedUrls = []

def findLinks(url):
    # make the get request
    result = requests.get(startUrl);    
    # make the get request
    result = requests.get(url);
    #print str(result.status_code) + " URL: " + url
    visitedUrls.append(url)

    # pass the html source to BeautifulSoup parser
    content = result.content    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        # all absolute paths hrefs and add to array     
        if "google.com" in link.get('href'):
            linksToCrawl.append(link.get('href'))
        # fix relative path urls and add to array
        elif link.get('href')[0] == '/':
            linksToCrawl.append("http://www.google.com" + link.get('href'))

    print "\nLinks to crawl:"
    print type(linksToCrawl)
    print str(len(linksToCrawl)) + "\n"
    print linksToCrawl
    print "Visited Urls:"
    print type(visitedUrls)
    print str(len(visitedUrls)) + "\n"
    print visitedUrls   
    print "\n"  

    return linksToCrawl

# start the spider
findLinks(startUrl) 
for link in linksToCrawl:
    findLinks(link)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "link-checker.py", line 54, in <module>
    findLinks(link)
  File "link-checker.py", line 33, in findLinks
    if "google.com" in link.get('href'):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: `link.get('href')` is returning `None`. You could try `link.get('href',[])` to make an iterable the default value returned when `get()` fails.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over (use the `in` keyword to check the contents of) `None`, which is the default returned from `get()` when it fails to find the provided name, so using an empty list as the default (second argument) will prevent the error:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    # all absolute paths hrefs and add to array     
    if "google.com" in link.get('href', []):
        linksToCrawl.append(link.get('href'))
```

You still may wish to confirm that you need `link.get('href')` to return something truthy before getting this far into the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me and I am passed the error now:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.get('href'):
        # all absolute paths hrefs and add to array     
        if "google.com" in link.get('href'):
```

Similar to testing for `is not None` although that did not work.  Thanks all